# webpack to create CSS component-scoped

Tags: css, webpack

I'm currently learning how to use webpack and I'm struggling a bit with CSS files. Basically, I'm using AngularJs 1.5 and TypeScript to create two components. Each of them have a template that contains a "div" element with the "button" class.

There is also a CSS file for each component that both contain a "class" called "button".

What I would like is to be able to do

```
require('./file.css')
```

to pack it into the resulting "app.bundle.js" file. This way, no additional requests are needed to load the css files. I succeeded in doing so by simply using "style-loader" and "css-loader".

My problem is that the CSS included in the "app.bundle.js" file is not really component-scoped, so the class "button" stay "button". Therefore, if I include both of my component on the same page, the style of the latest one is applied (two "button" classes are defined in the "style" tag of the page).

However, what I understood from [this article](http://glenmaddern.com/articles/css-modules), is that it would generate css with prefixes in the class name used to scope these classes just for the component, but here, the classes name is left untouched creating conflicts.

Is there a way to achieve what I want with webpack?

Comment: You probably haven't enabled the "module mode" of css-loader? https://github.com/css-modules/webpack-demo