# webpack: scoping all SCSS under vue app selector

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, sass

I am writing a vue app that renders inside a page on a "traditional" server-rendered site, in this container:

```
<div id="account-summary-container"></div>
```

Things work great when developing locally.  But when run within the context of the website there is alot of style collision, because both my app and the website's styles are global.  My app screws up styles on the entire site.

How can I scope all styles in my app to be local to the selector my app is rendered within?

My app uses bootstrap 4 styles which I am loading with `css-loader`.

I have webpack.config.js entrypoints like this:

```
entry: {
  app: ["./src/scss/styles.scss", "./src/app.js"]
},
```

and `styles.scss` looks like:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import '../css/feather.min.css';
@import '../css/icomoon-spinners.css';
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maven+Pro:400,500,700,900');
@import 'helpers/variables';
@import 'helpers/mixins';
@import 'helpers/placeholders';
...
```

I am thinking `css-modules` might be the answer, but I can't figure out how to tell `css-loader` to make ALL styles local to `#account-summary-container`.  I tried this in `styles.scss`:

```
:local(#account-summary-container) {
  composes: "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
  composes: "../css/feather.min.css";
  ...
}
```

And it scoffed at my lame attempt with:

```
Error: composition is only allowed when selector is single :local class name not in ":local(#account-summary-container)", "#account-summary-container" is weird
```

I'm wondering if I am approaching it totally wrong.  I'm hoping to not have to do alot of rewriting of styles.

Answer (score 0):

In order to target only components inside of your `Vue` instance you have to use `scoped styles`.  It is kind of a pain because you can't scope the `css` on the "main" `App.vue` file and let all children inherit it - you have to use `scoped styles` on each component that need it, which may result in more requests than you'd like..

As an example (I tested this and it should work)..

```
<template>
    <!--
      VUE/COMPONENT TEMPLATE
    -->
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    /* ***********************
         VUE/COMPONENT CODE
       *********************** */
  };
</script>

<!-- 
*********************************************************
***** SCOPE CSS PER COMPONENT ****************************
***** IMPORT VIA 'src="./path/to/cssfile.css"' ***********
**********************************************************
--> 
<style scoped src="../css/style.css">

</style>
```

Comment: Thanks Matt.  That's a good approach.  Though I am wondering if there's a way to accomplish this with webpack, for instances where I am not using vue.

Comment: I am not sure, to be honest.  It looks like it may be possible, but going to be tricky.. [From this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603538/webpack-to-create-css-component-scoped) post, it looks like `css-loader` module mode helped this person out (with an Angular app).. What other app are you planning on doing this on? If you plan on 'mixing' styles - you should prob go back to the "roots" of `css` and just give elements unique `id`'s or `name`'s....if you wrote the css file(s) you need for this Vue app in a unique fashion you wouldnt have to worry about any of this.

Comment: Thanks.  To answer your question, I have another webpack app that's plain javascript.  But I went down the vue scoped route and tried `<style scoped lang="scss" src="../styles.scss"></style>`.  Adding to the topmost parent component won't work, as you mentioned, because it will only apply to that component.  When I add that `<style>` to all components, the outputted css file is 2.4mb (whereas previously it was about 80k).  So, still searching.  Hoping I don't have to totally re-think/re-write the css.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yea I figured by scoping to each component it would cause duplicates like that. I still think your best bet is to prefix all of the classes and ids for the Vue app with something like `vue--some--class` or something very unique. I feel like you're looking for a complex solution for an easy problem. After all that's how css is designed - to have unique classes and ids. If I were you I would go back to the roots. Or you can change all of your selectors to recognize the "root" Vue div and only select elements under it. That's going to be the quickest fix imo.

Answer (score 0):

Found the [answer](https://codepen.io/trey/post/nesting-sass-includes).  Pretty simple.  Should had a V8 (conk).

```
.pony {
    @import 'sub';
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

Comment: That's the same as scoping your css to that particular div (aka changing selectors to only apply to the Vue app div) - essentially going back to css roots. Glad you found a fix.